# Transaction timeout for OleDbConnection.BeginnTransaction()

Tags: c#, ms-access, transactions, timeout

I have an application which uses a DataSet to accessing a MS Access database.

As I can not use *TransactionScope* (the provider *Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0* does not support it, furthermore I want to use  the same transaction across multiple function calls) I am going to use following construction:

```
var myTransaction = myTableAdapter.Connection.BeginTransaction();
…
…
…
myTransaction.Commit();
```

And now I am wondering:

1. how long the transaction timeout would be in this case?
   (It is not possible to set this timeout like the *TransactionScope* can)
2. can I set this timeout to a particular value?

I have not been able to find it out yet :-(
I only found the possibility to set a transaction timeout via *TransactionSettings*, but it seems to work with *TransactionScope* and *CommitableTransaction* only…

I will be very happy if anyone could provide some help.

(I am using C# .NET 3.5).